# UIWindow doesn't updating subviews after addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwindow, subviews

I'm adding a UIView as subview to current keyWindow and it shows fine.
Then when I update the subviews (UILabel, UIButton, UIImageView etc...) it doesn't get update.
I tried adding setNeedDisplay everywhere so it can update it but still no luck.

Adding to UIWindow:

```
trapAlarmActivity = [[TrapAlarm alloc] initWithUserInfo:params];
[trapAlarmActivity setNeedsDisplay];
[trapAlarmActivity.screenView setNeedsDisplay];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:trapAlarmActivity];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setNeedsDisplay];
```

Updating the UIWindow:

```
- (void)changeMessageBoxWithDistance:(NSInteger)distanceToTrap
{
    distanceToTrap += arc4random()%100;
    distance = distanceToTrap;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"************changeMessageBoxWithDistance: %i", distanceToTrap);

        trapType = globalTrap.getTrapType;

        if ([ref integerForKey:kUpdate_Distance] == kACTIVE && trapType != CAMERA_LASER)
        {
            self.labelDistance.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i %@", distance, NSLocalizedString(@"meters", nil)];
            self.labelDescription.text = globalTrap.getTrapDesc;
            self.labelTrapType.text = GetTrapTypeString(trapType);
        }
        else
        {
            self.labelDistance.text = globalTrap.getTrapDesc;
            self.labelDescription.text = GetTrapTypeString(trapType);
            self.labelTrapType.text = @"";
        }
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow setNeedsDisplay];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.firstObject setNeedsDisplay];

        /*NSEnumerator *frontToBackWindows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.reverseObjectEnumerator;
        for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows) {
            [window setNeedsDisplay];
        }*/
    });
}
```

**UPDATE-1:**

Updated code to work on main thread, still no luck.
Only 1st UIView added as a subview shown.

**UPDATE-2:**

recursiveDescription when the UIView is presented on top of the keyWindow:

```
(lldb) po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
<UIWindow: 0xd064f20; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd05ecd0>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xd05db90>>
   | <SWRevealView: 0xd126130; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd126250>>
   |    | <UIView: 0xd126400; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd0a2b00>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd126480>>
   |    |    | <UILayoutContainerView: 0xd0909a0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd093830>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0894b0>>
   |    |    |    | <UINavigationTransitionView: 0xd091310; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd091aa0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xd578160; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd578230>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xd12b620; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd12b420>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd12a370; frame = (0 64; 320 67); autoresize = BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd12a300>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableView: 0xe1d1600; frame = (0 191; 320 377); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd081790>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd025310>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewWrapperView: 0xd097cc0; frame = (0 0; 320 377); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xd097dd0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x12a48000; frame = (0 315; 320 63); text = ' '; autoresize = W; tag = 5; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a48190>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12a48a70; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a48d00>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a48c40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a48950; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x12a489c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12a481c0; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a492f0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a48230>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12a48260; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a482e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a48310; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a483c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a486e0; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = 'היום כולם ידעו על האפליקצ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a48790>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a49ae0; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = ' '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a49b90>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a490a0; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x12a48610>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x12a44230; frame = (0 252; 320 63); text = '  '; autoresize = W; tag = 4; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a443c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12a44ca0; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a44f30>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44e70>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a44b80; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44bf0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12a443f0; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a45520>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44460>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12a44490; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44510>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a44540; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a445f0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a44910; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = ' גלאי מכמונות סלולארי אתכ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a449c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a45d10; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = '  '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a45dc0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a452d0; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44840>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x12a40790; frame = (0 189; 320 63); text = '  '; autoresize = W; tag = 3; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a40920>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12a411b0; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a41440>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a41380>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a410e0; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0xd0b0590>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12a40950; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a41840>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a409c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12a409f0; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a40a70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a40aa0; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a40b50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a40e70; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = 'שתפו ודווחו לקיר שלנו, עד...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a40f20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a41f50; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = '  '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a42000>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a41570; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xd0b0f80>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x12a3cc40; frame = (0 126; 320 63); text = '   '; autoresize = W; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3cdd0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12a3d780; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a3da10>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3d950>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a3d690; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0xd0984e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12a3ce00; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a3dcd0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3ce70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12a3cea0; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3cf20>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a3cf50; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3d000>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a3d320; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = 'הוסיפו את גלאי מכמונות סל...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3d3d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a3e4b0; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = '   '; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3e560>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a3d200; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xd0ae1b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0x12a39020; frame = (0 63; 320 63); text = 'גלאי מכמונות סלולארי'; autoresize = W; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a391b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0x12a399f0; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd016a50>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0166e0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xd0168a0; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0xd016990>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0x12a39260; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a3a040>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a392d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x12a39300; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a39380>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a393b0; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a39460>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a39780; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = 'אפליקציית גלאי מכמונות מה...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a39830>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a3a960; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = 'גלאי מכמונות סלולארי'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a3aa10>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0x12a39660; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0xd016550>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCell: 0xd57b950; frame = (0 0; 320 63); text = 'בוקר טוב'; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57b5e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellScrollView: 0xd57c860; frame = (0 0; 320 63); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd57ce10>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57cad0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xd57c3f0; frame = (15 62; 305 1); layer = <CALayer: 0xd57c500>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UITableViewCellContentView: 0xd57bd60; frame = (0 0; 320 62.5); opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd081600>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57be50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd57c000; frame = (9 8; 45 45); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 32; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57c080>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd57c0b0; frame = (73 -15; 227 21); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 30; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57b0d0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd57c1c0; frame = (73 37; 227 21); text = 'יום טוב עם מלא הצלחה'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; tag = 31; layer = <CALayer: 0xd57c270>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12a36bc0; frame = (15 0; 290 62.5); text = 'בוקר טוב'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a36c70>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UITableViewCellSeparatorView: 0xd0afae0; frame = (15 62.5; 305 0.5); layer = <CALayer: 0x12a44b50>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <MOORefreshView: 0xd0a6ee0; frame = (0 -64; 320 64); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a7030>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIActivityIndicatorView: 0xd0a8100; frame = (20 22; 20 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a81b0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd0a8260; frame = (0 0; 20 20); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a82e0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd0adc90; frame = (17 7; 26 50); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd124eb0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd12a910; frame = (107 23; 106 18); text = 'Pull to refresh...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd124d00>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd578d70; frame = (0 373.5; 320 3.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd578e40>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd578f80; frame = (316.5 370; 3.5 7); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; autoresize = LM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd579050>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd12abd0; frame = (10 141; 40 40); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd12b450>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd0998a0; frame = (255 75; 45 45); autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd099830>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd098320; frame = (255 75; 45 45); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0983a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd129fa0; frame = (58 153; 242 21); text = 'You are part of 16 regist...'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd12a050>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd283e40; frame = (0 190; 320 1); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd239dc0>>
   |    |    |    | <UINavigationBar: 0xd090a20; frame = (0 20; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0xd091020>; layer = <CALayer: 0xd08fb70>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackground: 0xd090ae0; frame = (0 -20; 320 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0896a0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0xd099d60; frame = (0 0; 320 64); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0xd090440>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropEffectView: 0xd059680; frame = (0 0; 320 64); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CABackdropLayer: 0xd07a6c0>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xd088560; frame = (0 0; 320 64); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd07c130>>
   |    |    |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xd055ec0; frame = (0 0; 320 64); alpha = 0.85; hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd028480>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd090b80; frame = (0 64; 320 0.5); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd089460>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationItemView: 0xd09aae0; frame = (136 8; 48.5 27); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a1c30>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0xd0a1e70; frame = (0 2.5; 48.5 22); text = 'Home'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a1de0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UINavigationButton: 0xd285900; frame = (5 1; 62 40); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd089430>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd0a3cc0; frame = (11 0; 40 40); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0a4fc0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UINavigationBarBackIndicatorView: 0xd091120; frame = (8 12; 12.5 20.5); alpha = 0; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd091220>>
   | <TrapAlarm: 0xd07c8f0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd028b40>>
   |    | <UIToolbar: 0x12a1d640; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd0aed00>>
   |    |    | <_UIToolbarBackground: 0xd294410; frame = (0 0; 320 568); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd2944a0>>
   |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropView: 0xd2945e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UIBackdropViewLayer: 0xd2950f0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <_UIBackdropEffectView: 0xd27daf0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CABackdropLayer: 0xd27db60>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xd27db90; frame = (0 0; 320 568); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd27dbf0>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x1296bee0; frame = (0 -0.5; 320 0.5); autoresize = W+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1296beb0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0xd0bdcb0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xd00cb10>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd0b8930; frame = (0 0; 320 568); opaque = NO; autoresize = LM+RM+TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a49350>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd03c7f0; frame = (25 25; 265 128); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd28fed0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1296e330; frame = (27 27; 265 55); text = '190 Meters'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x12957000>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x12967d00; frame = (27 87; 265 32); text = '1 הדסה 90 ב"ש'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd26c580>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x1296d3e0; frame = (27 117; 265 32); text = 'Netroads Pilot'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd242de0>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0xd12edc0; frame = (290 20; 30 30); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd137d00>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd293cb0; frame = (0 0; 30 30); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd293d30>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0x129668e0; frame = (27 440; 120 35); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd2168d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd272a70; frame = (0 0; 120 35); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd2867d0>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x129666e0; frame = (19 6; 81 22); text = 'Not exists'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd2fbce0>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0xd084ec0; frame = (160 440; 120 35); hidden = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xd008230>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xd284600; frame = (0 0; 120 35); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1293a970>>
   |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x1296bb10; frame = (36 6; 48 22); text = 'Exists'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1296bbc0>>

(lldb)
```

**UPDATE-3:**

I ended up turning the UIView to UIViewController and showing it via:

```
appDelegate.window.rootViewController = testViewController;
[appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

And dismissing it via pushing back the original viewController.

Comment: can you change the line [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:trapAlarmActivity]; as [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate].window addSubview:trapAlarmActivity] and try?

Comment: What thread is this running on?

Comment: @jai I added the subview to appDelegate.window but it won't help since i'm not using the appDelegate.window in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions".

Comment: @JefferyThomas I'm running it on main thread via "dispatch_async()".

Comment: but your code not update via main thread @IdanMoshe

Comment: I updated my code here, take a look :)

Comment: As a side, don't use `arc4random()%100` use `arc4random_uniform(100)` see [arc4random(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html)

Comment: What does `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] recursiveDescription]` show?

Comment: There is no 'recursiveDescription' in UIWindow.

Comment: It's a hidden method of UIView. See [iOS Debugging Magic > UIKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010638-CH1-SUBSECTION34)

Comment: @JefferyThomas I can't seem to understand how shall I install it.

Comment: I did it with pausing the app and writing it in the console, I updated my code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47168/discussion-between-idan-moshe-and-jeffery-thomas)

Answer (score 0):

call `setNeedsDisplay` method on your application’s main thread when you want to adjust the layout of a view’s subviews.

Comment: That's what I did just before the end "[self setNeedsDisplay];".

Comment: did you try this setNeedsUpdateConstraints

Comment: Yes I did, still nothing.